# ng-if date comparison using the == operator

Tags: angularjs

```
ng-if="{{(Date | date:"dd/mm/yyyy") == (question.DateTimeEnd | date:"dd/mm/yyyy")}}"
```

I have this expression  where  `$scope.Date = new Date()`.

I get a parser error . i am wondering if this can be achieved using the `==` operator in the `mustache expression` itself.

Comment: Why using `{{}}` (expressions) when you have `ng-if`?

Comment: My bad . i was completely oblivious of it because i copied t from my markup where i was displaying it  . until somebody pointed it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like this. you don't need {{}} in ng-if and also "" in date format.

```
  ng-if="(Date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy') == (question.DateTimeEnd | date:'dd/MM/yyyy')"
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Date = '20160313T00:00:00';
  
  $scope.DateTimeEnd = '20160313T00:00:00';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   
        <p  ng-if="(Date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy') == (DateTimeEnd | date:'dd/MM/yyyy')" ng-bind="DateTimeEnd | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'"></p>
   
 </div>
```

Comment: ok that didn't throw any error so i'l just check it to see if i am getting the desired result

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

   // Convert Date into long format for comparision by using .getTime()

   $scope.tempDate = new Date();
   $scope.date = $scope.tempDate.getTime();

   $scope.DateTime = $scope.question.DateTimeEnd.getTime(); 
})
```

Then use `ng-if`

```
ng-if="{{date == DateTime}}"
```

Or you can print your result in Date format also

```
ng-if="{{date == DateTime | date : "dd/MM/yyyy"}}"
```

Comment: i wanted to avoid using getTime() . Didn't want time precision

Comment: yes but whenever you want to compare `Date` that time you should compare it in long so you will get error less and perfect comparision